# Youtube player in UIWebView in ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube, modalviewcontroller

I am working on an app targeted for > iOS 4. In this app I display a UIWebView as modalView (inside an UIViewController which is pushed from an UITableViewController living in an UINavigationController ;)):

```
SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[settings release];
[navController release];
```

This shows a modal view with a UITableView. Once a specific row is tapped my browser view controller is pushed:

```
        WebBrowserViewController *vc = [[WebBrowserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebBrowserView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [vc goToUrl:@"http://www.example.com"];
        [vc release];
```

Inside the WebBrowserViewController is an UIWebView and some browser controls (address bar, back and refresh buttons). This all works as expected.

On to the problem:
If there are youtube videos embedded on a website and those are clicked the youtube player launches fullscreen. Once I close the youtube player (Done button) the player closes, apparently my modal view closes too and the app crashes after showing my root view controller for a second.

This is the console output:

```
2011-02-24 14:52:51.109 MyApp[498:307] modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x14eda0
2011-02-24 14:52:51.113 MyApp[498:307] modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x14b590
2011-02-24 14:52:51.117 MyApp[498:307] modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x14c630
2011-02-24 14:52:51.262 MyApp[498:307] modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x14eda0
2011-02-24 14:52:51.270 MyApp[498:307] *** -[CALayer sublayers]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x178fe0
```

My guess is that once the youtube player is launched my modal view controller is released and jumping back to it fails. I wasn't successful in finding the place to add a retain or similar …

Anyone seen this happen and can give me a hint what to do?

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: I am seeing this behavior in my app as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Reg: modifying layer that is being finalized....... [CALayer frame]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe43c520](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956413/reg-modifying-layer-that-is-being-finalized-calayer-frame-message-sen)

The error `"modifying layer that is being finalized"` occurs when you are trying to modify the properties of a `CALayer` when it is in the process of being deallocated. I've seen this happen when I've accidentally used an accessor to clear a property on a `CALayer` while within that layer's `-dealloc` method.