# "modifying layer that is being finalized" error when popping navigation controller

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewanimation

I'm using navigation controller for my app. In one of views I have an animation that is fired by timer. 
When I click back I get this message in console:

```
modifying layer that is being finalized
```

I think that it's because animation is still running after dealloc. I found how to remove animations but it's not working in this case:

```
[toolbarView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Is there a different way to release this viewcontroller without problems?

Comment: Are you doing this in the background thread?

Comment: No, that is normal thread. I just found that it's not because of animations, but just release problem. Instead of `[toolbarView release];` i used `[toolbarView removeFromSuperview]` and now it's releasing properly, but I don't know if it is a right way to do this...

Comment: Have a look on this answer. I was also having same problem and found the right answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956413/reg-modifying-layer-that-is-being-finalized-calayer-frame-message-sent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to releasing problem.
in my case, i m allocating a class inside the method and that i am pushing to next view controller .
after that i m releasing that class.so it is showing that error.

solution....
i initialized in .h and released in dealloc.now it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, it was caused by not releasing properly.